# Gem install configuration in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, bundler, pg

When I run `bundle install`, I get errors with the `pg` gem (it needs to know where `pg_config` is located). I can easily resolve that by installing it manually `gem install ... --with-pg-config=...`, but I'm getting the same error when pushing to Heroku with `git push heroku master`. I can't manually install it there, since the dyno has a read-only filesystem. Hence, is there a way to specify that I want to use `--with-pg-config=...` in the Gemfile itself so that Heroku will follow the instructions on-the-fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the gem install configuration options in the bundle config.

Bundler retrieves its configuration from the local application (app/.bundle/config) environment variables and then user's home directory (~/.bundle/config), in that order of priority.

A very common example, the mysql gem, requires Snow Leopard users to pass configuration flags to gem install to specify where to find the mysql_config executable.

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Since the specific location of that executable can change from machine to machine, you can specify these flags on a per-machine basis.

```
bundle config build.mysql --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

After running this command, every time bundler needs to install the mysql gem, it will pass along the flags you specified.

Visit [bundle-config](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html) for more info.